# jQuery UI dateFormat not changing format

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a datepicker that I want to apply a custom format to but it does not work.

```
 $(function () { 
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
    });
})
```

But the custom format is not being applied, it stay with the default "mm/dd/yy"

Any clues what else can impact the fomating? Its an old mvc .net project with EF. Can some of the EF tags impact this??

Any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the input guys but I found the issue - turns out there was a refrence to another js libary called bootstrap-datepicker.js in the solution that was interfering with the jQuery UI libary. Sorry for the bad question

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons this can fail is if you're making two calls to `datepicker()` in the same file, and one is overwriting the results of the other.

HTML

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" class="datepicker">
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
$(function () { 
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
    }); // Initialized once
});

$('.datepicker').datepicker(); // Initialized again without any options
```

Comment: thanks good guess, but unfortunatly this isn't the case either

Answer (score 0):

Full Example is here with your needed format:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Format date</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    $("#format").on( "change", function() {
      $("#datepicker").datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", $( this ).val() );
    });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" size="30"></p>
 
<p>Format options:<br>
  <select id="format">
    <option value="mm/dd/yy">Default - mm/dd/yy</option>
    <option value="yy-mm-dd">ISO 8601 - yy-mm-dd</option>
    <option value="dd-mm-yy">Other - dd-mm-yy</option>
 <option value="d M, y">Short - d M, y</option>
    <option value="d MM, y">Medium - d MM, y</option>
    <option value="DD, d MM, yy">Full - DD, d MM, yy</option>
    <option value="&apos;day&apos; d &apos;of&apos; MM &apos;in the year&apos; yy">With text - 'day' d 'of' MM 'in the year' yy</option>
  </select>
</p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks I tried differne tversions of your code (incl the original) but it does not work

Comment: @MajaOkholm its working also in example. please share your full code.

Comment: I realise its from the documentation so you are right that it should be working but it's not working when I past it into my project. I guess something must be wrong in my setup because this should be simple but I cant fingure out what the problem is :-(